# Minimum google play service version for min Sdk Version 17

Tags: google-maps, google-play-services, android-min-sdk

My application minimum sdk version is 17 and i have map, that old google play services do not support it. I want to know from which versions of google play service do not support this sdk version?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of required SDK's for different android versions:

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk

check, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

i find another solution to my problem. in fact i wanted to handle the devices that not support google map because their google play services are not updated. so i use code below

*`int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
//my handling code
}`*

to handle.